# Fixing Replay Attack. Someone added tx to bypass executing by adding an amount not available in the wallet

Tags: anchor, solana-program, security, idl

So, we had a coinflip sort of logic implemented and sols kept in a pool to be rewarded to someone who wins with a randomizer code in place using blockhash. However, right after we deployed, someone did append transactions to program via CLI i believe to reject a transaction by keeping a low balance (adding it to the end of tx to add a larger number) so in case the user wins, the tx gets successful otherwise cancels out.

here's a link to solscan
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3zwNBhzLdr5vaKrmUtGcGwUUqQF4sr4dR6QmhEK7ZTM5aihAkZ4zmazvWu7RJQpBmxWNW1hEUYSE2vGuceZrnLa5

still figuring how we can stop anyone from interacting with the program in this way?